# Why doesn't this jQuery function return anything?

Tags: jquery, function, null, return

I've searched for hours trying to fix this jQuery/JS code, But It just doesn't seem to want to return anything.

```
var result = getURLS(); // this is always blank

function getURLS() {
    var urls = [];
    var URL_record = Parse.Object.extend("URL_record");
    var query = new Parse.Query(URL_record);

    query.equalTo("user", Parse.User.current());
    query.ascending("date");

    query.find({
        success : function(results) {
            var tempURLS = [];
            $.each(results, function(index, record) {
                urls.push(record.get("shortURL") + " " + record.get("longURL"));
            });
        },
        error : function(error) {

        }
    });
    return urls;
}
```

Although if I create an alert function from this particular function:

```
success : function(results) {
    var tempURLS = [];
    $.each(results, function(index, record) {
        urls.push(record.get("shortURL") + " " + record.get("longURL"));
    });
        alert(urls);
},
```

It seems to alert fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Let me guess: `query.find` is (yet another) async code?

Comment: What does `tempURLS` do? It isn't used anywhere.

Comment: query.find is an async code but I wouldn't get a straight answer from anywhere else. and tempURLS was used earlier for debugging, it's not meant to be there.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `Parse` but as @raina77ow said, I'm assuming `query.find` is an asynchronous request. Basically that means the request is sent and then the code continues without waiting, which means it goes and returns `urls`, before the code inside of `success` is executed. `urls` is empty before `success` is executed.

Comment: so is there some sort of function to make it wait until the code inside `success` has executed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

query.find is asynchronous, you'll need to set the variable inside of the success function then call the code that uses result.

```
var result;
getURLS();

function getURLS() {
    var urls = [];
    var URL_record = Parse.Object.extend("URL_record");
    var query = new Parse.Query(URL_record);

    query.equalTo("user", Parse.User.current());
    query.ascending("date");

    query.find({
        success : function(results) {
            var tempURLS = [];
            $.each(results, function(index, record) {
                urls.push(record.get("shortURL") + " " + record.get("longURL"));
            });
            result = urls;
            // call code that uses result here
            processResults(result);
        },
        error : function(error) {

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that query.get is asynchronous after being stumped for hours. Until I stripped everything else out of my  $(function () {}); block and saw on the console that the query fires after the block. The eventual idea is to load models and views into a Facebook app, which also has an asynchronous init function. I did not expect the Parse query to also be asynchronous.